# How can i fetch json data without key in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can i fetch JSON data without key in flutter?

I don't need to create a map to fetch it, i have an url to call it and the json is composed of one single int value. How can i fetch it?

Comment: What does the response body look like?  Is it just a bare number like `47`, or is it in a list, like `[47]`, or is it in a JSON object, like `{"key": 47}`?

Comment: it is only a int value, a number like: `2`

Comment: Then you need only `var theValue = int.parse(response.body);`  No JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var client = http.Client();
String url = "url";
Response response = await client.get(url);
print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
print('Response body: ${json.decode((response.body))}');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is package called `http` that can help you to fetch data from your API

so this how you proceed

import http package
`import 'package:http/http.dart';`

then send request to your API by
`Response response = await get(url);` this is a asynchronous methosd so make sure to add `async` in your function

So, as you asked you don't want to create Map variable
this is how you access it
`int x = jsonDecode(response.body)['the key']`

make sure you import `import 'dart:convert';` as it a dependency

if you still have issues comment down below.
Regards,
Roshan